# Regular expression - File name not matching desired pattern

Tags: regex

Trying to figure out why this file name does not match this regular expression pattern:

- File name: `file.txt`
- Pattern: `^(([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+[[.]{1}([a-zA-Z0-9])+]{1})$`

I am allowing name and only one file extension:

- for the name I use this: 
  `([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+`
  which is any number of letters, numbers, underscores and dashes.
- for the extension I use this: 
  `[[.]{1}([a-zA-Z0-9])+]{1}`
  which is only one extension, that has exactly one dot followed by letters or numbers.

The extension pattern is the one that fails, and I don't understand why.

Test cases:

- These filenames should pass: `file.txt`, `fi-le.t7t`
- These filenames should not pass: `file.txt.doc`, `file.` , `file` (the last one, no extension)

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question and use a more descriptive title than "Regular expression". I took the liberty of formatting the rest of it properly for you.

Comment: The right question is what made you think that it should match it?

Comment: `[[.]{1}([a-zA-Z0-9])+]{1}` ... ok so you expect exactly one of these characters `[.]{1}([a-zA-Z0-9])+`. How should that match `.txt`? Or why do you think you can wrap `[]` into another `[]`?

Comment: I think I'm using the parenthesis `(` and `)` in the wrong place.

Comment: Error: Regex Construction .. 

Invalid collation character.

`^(([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+[[.<<<HERE>>>]{1}([a-zA-Z0-9])+]{1})$`

Comment: Since you're new here, please don't forget to **mark the answer accepted** which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

You only need to wrap a term in parentheses `(` and `)` if you actually want the regex engine to capture those (so you can grab their value from a match). If you don't need to capture them, you just want to find whether a piece of text matches, you can get rid of the parentheses from this regular expression.

Rather than use the slightly ungainly looking `[.]` to represent a literal period character, you can simply escape the sensitive character with a backslash: `\.`.

Also, by default regex will expect a sequence to match exactly once, so you don't need to follow a term with `{1}` because that's the default.

And I'm not sure what you were intending with the term entirely wrapped in square brackets `[` and `]`, but square brackets only need to be used if you want to create a character class (to define set of acceptable characters) such as your existing `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`.

Comment: You can even use `\w` and `\d` in the capture groups: `^([\w\d-_]+)\.([\w\d]+)$`

Comment: @Darkproduct `\w` includes `\d` and `_`. Also since we are not sure what engine OP uses to run it, we shouldn't suggest these shorthands.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$` worked like a charm.